# Avoid minifying certain packages in meteor

Tags: node.js, npm, meteor, ejs, minify

In my project, I have some npm dependencies which use ejs templates - this works fine locally, but as soon as they are minified for production using standard-minifier-js, the packages crash because the template can't find required components.

Can I tell the standard-minifier-js to skip certain npm packages, or is there any other way to have ejs templates run in production?

Edit: I also tried running in production without standard-minifier-js, everything works fine.

Comment: You can write your own minifier based on Standard minifier and Slip those modules

Comment: That would mean breaking off from official future updates or having to constantly drag those changes to new versions in the future... I'd prefer a less work-around solution. Like if there was some kind of flag in packages.json I can set or something of the sort... I'd be a bit surprised if there isn't a proper way to skip a package

Comment: The minifier [ignores all files](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/standard-minifier-js/plugin/minify-js.js#L119) that end with `.min.js` so you should be fine by just renaming (refactoring) your filename to use this ending.

Comment: I tried that without success. What finally worked was to remove them from the npm packages entirely, and directly loading the pre-built packages straight from a CDN, this way they're not touched by the minifier.